# How to generate documentation for python project including private/protected classes with pdoc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdoc

I am trying to generate documentation for my python project with `pdoc` module by following this [article](https://medium.com/blueriders/python-autogenerated-documentation-3-tools-that-will-help-document-your-project-c6d7623814ef).

I noticed that all the classes, methods, etc starting with `__` (private/protected ones) are missing in the generated documentation.

This is the sample.py

```
class __Members:
    def __test():
        pass

class seedoc:
    ''' see me '''
    pass
```

This is how I generated the documentation with pdoc

```
$pdoc --html sample.py
html/sample.html
```

I see only public class in the generated documentation as per this screenshot:
[image]

Can someone please help me figure out a way to get over this limitation and generate the documentation with all the private/protected members? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pdoc only [extracts public API members](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#what-objects-are-documented) (not prefixed with an underscore) by convention.

You may be able to override this behavior, on a module level, by defining [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), or, more generally, by specifying overrides in the [`__pdoc__` dict](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#overriding-docstrings-with-__pdoc__), either manually for a few members, or automatically yet hackish, somewhat like:

```py
# Specified at the end of each module that contains private
# classes/methods that need to be exposed
__pdoc__ = {name: True
            for name, klass in globals().items()
            if name.startswith('_') and isinstance(klass, type)}
__pdoc__.update({f'{name}.{member}': True
                 for name, klass in globals().items()
                 if isinstance(klass, type)
                 for member in klass.__dict__.keys()
                 if member not in {'__module__', '__dict__', 
                                   '__weakref__', '__doc__'}})
```

Alternatively, you should just rename your members if they are part of your public API.

Also note, Python by default defines [dozens of dunder members](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/) on objects, most of which have standard meaning or are internal:

```py
>>> class Cls:
...     pass

>>> dir(Cls)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__']
```